# Log4j2: configure TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy programatically - "Arguments given for RollingFile are invalid: field 'policy' has invalid value 'null'"

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am migrating a project from log4j to log4j2 and one of logger is for some reason configured not with properties file but programtically. Original code:

```
String logKey = getRootFolder().replaceAll("/", "_");
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(logKey);

Layout layout = new PatternLayout("%-5p [%t]: %m%n");
Appender newAppender = new DailyRollingFileAppender(layout, "path-to-file", "'.'yyyy-MM-dd");
logger.addAppender(newAppender);
```

So basically I need to have a file that is rolled out on daily basis and make sure the configuration is not affecting other loggers configured by props file. All my attempts so far are failing with *field 'policy' has invalid value 'null'* error. This is what I tried:

```
 final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Current3.class);
        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder
                = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
        AppenderComponentBuilder rollingFile
                = builder.newAppender("rolling", "RollingFile");
        rollingFile.addAttribute("fileName", "C:/Users/Damian/Desktop/o3.log");
        
        //roll out each minute for tests only
        rollingFile.addAttribute("filePattern", "o3-rolling-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log.zip");
        rollingFile.addAttribute("policy", "time");

        builder.add(rollingFile);

        LayoutComponentBuilder standard
                = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout");
        standard.addAttribute("pattern", "%d my pattern [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable");

        rollingFile.add(standard);
        Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
        //log info messages in a loop
```

Attempt 2 (on basis of apache docs from [https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#:~:text=This%20example%20shows%20how%20to%20create%20a%20configuration%20that%20includes%20a%20RollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#:%7E:text=This%20example%20shows%20how%20to%20create%20a%20configuration%20that%20includes%20a%20RollingFileAppender).

```
final  Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("MyTestLogger");

        ConfigurationBuilder< BuiltConfiguration > builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setStatusLevel( Level.INFO);
        builder.setConfigurationName("RollingBuilder");
        // create a console appender
        AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target",
                ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
        appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
                .addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] pattern for console %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
        builder.add( appenderBuilder );
// create a rolling file appender
        LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
                .addAttribute("pattern", "%d my pattern [%t] %-5level: %msg%n");
        ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicy = builder.newComponent("Policies")
          //      .addComponent(builder.newComponent("CronTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("schedule", "0 0 0 * * ?"))
                .addComponent(builder.newComponent("TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("modulate", "true"));

        appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("rolling", "RollingFile")
                .addAttribute("fileName", "C:/Users/Damian/Desktop/04.log")
                .addAttribute("filePattern", "C:/Users/Damian/Desktop/04.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.zip")
                .add(layoutBuilder)
                .addComponent(triggeringPolicy);
     //   appenderBuilder.addComponent(builder.newComponent("DefaultRolloverStrategy").addAttribute("max", Integer.MAX_VALUE));

        builder.add(appenderBuilder);

    // create the new logger
     //  builder.newLogger( Current4.class.getName(), Level.INFO);
        builder.add( builder.newLogger( "MyTestLogger", Level.INFO )
                .add( builder.newAppenderRef( "rolling" ) )
                .addAttribute( "additivity", false ) );

        builder.add( builder.newRootLogger( Level.INFO)
                .add( builder.newAppenderRef( "rolling" ) ) );
        LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
    // log info messages in a loop...
```

I was not able to find many helpful examples for TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.
What am I missing - can anyone help please?

Comment: Since you don't want to create a new `Configuration`, but modify one obtained from a file, check [Log4J2 RollingFileAppender programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70648770/11748454). See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70532108/11748454) for the difference between the two programmatic approaches.

Comment: I got it working "in isolation" using Sirop's idea from (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62192721/initiate-log4j2-rollingfileappender-in-java?rq=1) but I still have one small issue with loggers added at runtime. I will post a new question not to mess up. Thank you